# Ansible - kubernetes plugin is not changing the cluster context

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, azure-aks, ansible-inventory

Inventory file (inventory/k8s.yaml):

```
plugin: kubernetes.core.k8s
connections:
  - kubeconfig: ~/.kube/config
    context: 'cluster-2'
```

Task file (roles/common/tasks/main.yaml):

```
# Method 1: Using `kubernetes.core` plugin to list the pod names:
- name: Get a list of all pods from any namespace
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    kind: Pod
  register: pod_list
- name: Print pod names
  debug:
    msg: "pod_list: {{ pod_list | json_query('resources[*].metadata.name') }} "

# Method 2: Using `shell` command to list the pod names:
- name: Get node names
  shell: kubectl get pods
  register: pod_list2
- name: Print pod names
  debug:
    msg: "{{ pod_list2.stdout }}"
```

Ansible config (ansible.cfg):

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, auto, yaml, ini, kubernetes.core.k8s
```

Main file (main.yaml):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - azure.azcollection
    - kubernetes.core
  roles:
    - "common"
```

Running command to execute task: `ansible-playbook main.yaml -i cluster-2/k8s.yaml -e role=common -e cluster_name=cluster-2`

Question:
I am running the above configs to run get the pods from the remote cluster mentioned in the inventory file. But, the problem is, I am still getting the pod names from the local cluster and not the cluster-2 in Method 1 and 2.

k8s plugin should get the list of pods from cluster-2 as described in the inventory file. How can I connect to remote kubernetes cluster?

I also checked output with `-vvvv`:

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.14.0]
config file = /Users/test/u/apps/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/Users/test/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /Users/test/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
ansible collection location = /Users/test/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
executable location = /Users/test/Library/Python/3.9/bin/ansible-playbook
python version = 3.9.12 (main, Mar 26 2022, 15:52:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] (/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9)
jinja version = 3.1.2
libyaml = True
Using /Users/test/u/apps/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Loading collection kubernetes.core from /Users/test/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use both the kubernetes inventory plugin **and** the `k8s_info` module, and because of that you're getting conflicting results. The two don't have anything to do with each other.

### The inventory module

The kubernetes inventory module is -- I think -- a weird beast; it produces an ansible inventory in which the pods in your cluster are presented as Ansible hosts. To see a list of all the pod names in your cluster, you could write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Print pod names
    debug:
      msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

This will respect the context you've configured in your kubernetes inventory plugin configuration. For example, if I have in `inventory/k8s.yaml` the following:

```
plugin: kubernetes.core.k8s
connections:
  - kubeconfig: ./kubeconfig
    context: 'kind-cluster2'
```

Then the above playbook will list the pod names from `kind-cluster2`, regardless of the `current-context` setting in my `kubeconfig` file. In my test environment, this produces:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Print pod names] *********************************************************
ok: [kubernetes] => {
    "msg": "kubernetes"
}
ok: [coredns-565d847f94-2shl6_coredns] => {
    "msg": "coredns-565d847f94-2shl6_coredns"
}
ok: [coredns-565d847f94-md57c_coredns] => {
    "msg": "coredns-565d847f94-md57c_coredns"
}
ok: [kube-dns] => {
    "msg": "kube-dns"
}
ok: [etcd-cluster2-control-plane_etcd] => {
    "msg": "etcd-cluster2-control-plane_etcd"
}
ok: [kube-apiserver-cluster2-control-plane_kube-apiserver] => {
    "msg": "kube-apiserver-cluster2-control-plane_kube-apiserver"
}
ok: [kube-controller-manager-cluster2-control-plane_kube-controller-manager] => {
    "msg": "kube-controller-manager-cluster2-control-plane_kube-controller-manager"
}
ok: [kube-scheduler-cluster2-control-plane_kube-scheduler] => {
    "msg": "kube-scheduler-cluster2-control-plane_kube-scheduler"
}
ok: [kindnet-nc27b_kindnet-cni] => {
    "msg": "kindnet-nc27b_kindnet-cni"
}
ok: [kube-proxy-9chgt_kube-proxy] => {
    "msg": "kube-proxy-9chgt_kube-proxy"
}
ok: [local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-925v5_local-path-provisioner] => {
    "msg": "local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-925v5_local-path-provisioner"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
coredns-565d847f94-2shl6_coredns : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
coredns-565d847f94-md57c_coredns : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
etcd-cluster2-control-plane_etcd : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kindnet-nc27b_kindnet-cni  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kube-apiserver-cluster2-control-plane_kube-apiserver : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kube-controller-manager-cluster2-control-plane_kube-controller-manager : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kube-dns                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kube-proxy-9chgt_kube-proxy : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kube-scheduler-cluster2-control-plane_kube-scheduler : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
kubernetes                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-925v5_local-path-provisioner : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The key point here is that your inventory will consist of a list of pods. I've never found this particularly useful.

### The `k8s_info` module

The `k8s_info` queries a kubernetes cluster for a list of objects. It doesn't care about your inventory configuration -- it will run on whichever target host you've defined for your play (probably `localhost`) and perform the rough equivalent of `kubectl get <whatever>`. If you want to use an explicit context, you need to set that as part of your module parameters. For example, to see a list of pods in `kind-cluster2`, I could use the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
        kind: pod
        kubeconfig: ./kubeconfig
        context: kind-cluster2
      register: pods

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ pods.resources | json_query('[].metadata.name') }}"
```

Which in my test environment produces as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [kubernetes.core.k8s_info] ************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "coredns-565d847f94-2shl6",
        "coredns-565d847f94-md57c",
        "etcd-cluster2-control-plane",
        "kindnet-nc27b",
        "kube-apiserver-cluster2-control-plane",
        "kube-controller-manager-cluster2-control-plane",
        "kube-proxy-9chgt",
        "kube-scheduler-cluster2-control-plane",
        "local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-925v5"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

In conclusion: you probably want to use `k8s_info` rather than the inventory plugin, and you'll need to configure the module properly by setting the `context` (and possibly the `kubeconfig`) parameters when you call the module.

---

> Is there any way I can define context and kubeconfig outside of the tasks (globally) if I am using k8s_info module?

According to [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html), you could set the `K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG` and `K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT` environment variables if you want to globally configure the settings for the `k8s_info` module. You could also write your task like this:

```
    - kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
        kind: pod
        kubeconfig: "{{ k8s_kubeconfig }}"
        context: "{{ k8s_context }}"
      register: pods
```

And then define the `k8s_kubeconfig` and `k8s_context` variables somewhere else in your Ansible configuration (e.g., as group vars). This makes it easy to retarget things to a different cluster with only a single change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way I can define context and kubeconfig outside of the tasks (globally) if I am using k8s_info module?

Comment: I've udpated the question to address your comments.